# Android Inflater/View Exception

Tags: android

I am trying to add a layout(profile_upload)to my custom AlertDialog which is inside Profile.java
for The first time it works fine. but when i close  AlertDialog and again click on  the button it crashes sayng 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first 
Profile.java

```
package com.example.accer.sportsgr;


import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageButton profile_btn;
  AlertDialog.Builder alert;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    TextView tx_img_name;
    Button btn_prfil_upld,btn_pic_choose;
    ImageView img_prfl;
    View v;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);


        profile_btn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.user_profile_photo);


         alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        inflater=Profile.this.getLayoutInflater();
        if (v == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_upload, null, false);
        } else {
            ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).removeView(v);
        }
        alert.setView(v);


        btn_prfil_upld=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload_profile_pic);
        btn_pic_choose=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_choose_profile_pic);
        img_prfl=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.img_profile_upload);
        tx_img_name=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tx_img_name);
        btn_prfil_upld.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_pic_choose.setOnClickListener(this);


        profile_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                alert.setTitle("Update Profile Picture");
                alert.show();

            }
        });


    }

    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null)
        {
            Uri filepath=data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),filepath);
                tx_img_name.setText(filepath.toString());
                img_prfl.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id=view.getId();
        switch (id)
        {
            case R.id.btn_choose_profile_pic :
                    showFileChooser();
                    break;
            case R.id.btnUpload_profile_pic:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

profile_upload.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose Image"
        android:id="@+id/btn_choose_profile_pic" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/img_profile_upload" />


   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tx_img_name"
       android:textAlignment="center"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:textSize="20dp"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Upload Image"
        android:id="@+id/btnUpload_profile_pic" />


</LinearLayout>
```

activity_profile.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header_cover_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/navigation_header_image"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/user_profile_photo"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_cover_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_imageview"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:clickable="true"/>
    <!-- android:src="@drawable/profile"-->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_cover_image"
        android:background="#ebca0707"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="24dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/add_friend"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_user_add"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/drop_down_option_menu"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drop_down_option_menu"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_profile_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_profile_short_bio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/user_profile_name"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Error Log:

```
2-17 16:17:47.395 13465-13465/com.example.accer.sportsgr E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.accer.sportsgr, PID: 13465
                                                                            java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4454)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4295)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4267)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.setupCustomContent(AlertController.java:613)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:452)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:215)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:258)
                                                                                at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:389)
                                                                                at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:293)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:956)
                                                                                at com.example.accer.sportsgr.Profile$1.onClick(Profile.java:98)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Show the contents of `activity_profile.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {



            }
        });
```

removeall views in this, it will call when u press the navigation back button

Comment: did my answer help u or u figured out on ur own?

Comment: yeah I followed Your suggestion. thank you once again.

Comment: u will see a tick to the left of my answer...below the upvote counter

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can preserve AlertDialog instance through AlertDialog.Builder.create() instead of AlertDialog.Builder instance.
If you use custom view, dialog will be created and then the custom view will be attached to dialog window every time AlertDialog.Builder.show().

```
public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    AlertDialog dialog;
    ImageButton profile_btn;
    TextView tx_img_name;
    Button btn_prfil_upld, btn_pic_choose;
    ImageView img_prfl;
    View v;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        profile_btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.user_profile_photo);
        profile_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(dialog == null) {
                    dialog = getBuilder().create();
                }
                dialog.setTitle("Update Profile Picture");
                dialog.show();

            }
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    private AlertDialog.Builder getBuilder() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        inflater = Profile.this.getLayoutInflater();
        if (v == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_upload, null, false);
        } else {
            ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).removeView(v);
        }
        alert.setView(v);


        btn_prfil_upld = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload_profile_pic);
        btn_pic_choose = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_choose_profile_pic);
        img_prfl = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_profile_upload);
        tx_img_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tx_img_name);
        btn_prfil_upld.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_pic_choose.setOnClickListener(this);
        return alert;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.btn_choose_profile_pic:
                break;
            case R.id.btnUpload_profile_pic:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Can you Please Explain more about AlertDialog  ,   AlertDialog.builder , Dialog.

Comment: or a link would do. I googled but coudn't find satisfactory answer.

Comment: I modified part of your code. I wish it gives you a help.

Comment: tanq that helped.